# Read from text file, store data into corresponding structure every 6 element, and then form an array

Tags: vb.net

The text file contains the following: inside the [], anything inside () was not in the text file, just for clarification

[1(ID)

Jimmy(First name)

Paul (Last name)

78 (marks1)

80 (marks2)

92 (marks3)

2

Ben

James

67

82

73
]

I created a structure that holds student details including their name, id, marks in each subject.

```
Private Structure StudInfo
    Public FName As String
    Public LName As String
    Public StudentId As Integer
    Public ScMark As Integer
    Public EnMark As Integer
    Public MaMark As Integer
```

The program needs to read the first six elements in a row, storing each element into the corresponding structure type, then let it become the first element of an array"students()", and then next six elements, let it become the second element of that array. I have no idea how to use loops to do that.

```
Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
    'create an array that hold student details
    Dim Students() As StudInfo

    ' read from text file 
    Dim FileNum As Integer = FreeFile()
    Dim TempS As String = ""
    Dim TempL As String
    FileOpen(FileNum, "some.text", OpenMode.Input)
    Do Until EOF(FileNum)
        TempL = LineInput(FileNum)
        TempS = TempL + vbCrLf
    Loop
End Sub
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a BinaryReader (which takes a IO.Stream as it's constructor), then you can read the data type you want, into the variable you want.

The problem you will have is the data will not be searchable (ie. you cannot read the 30th record, unless you physically read the first 29, because the strings are of variable length, and therefore the record is variable length), this also applies to modifying a record (you cant make it bigger, because it will overwrite the next record).

The answer is to work with fixed length records, or field offsets or fixed length strings. Then you will have a records of predictable size, and you can determine the amount of records by dividing the file length by the record size.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Students As New List(Of StudInfo)

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Students.Clear()
        Dim fileName = "c:\some folder\directory\someFile.txt"
        Using sr As New System.IO.StreamReader(fileName)
            Dim value As Integer
            Dim strValue As String

            While Not sr.EndOfStream
                Try
                    Dim student As New StudInfo
                    strValue = sr.ReadLine().Trim("[]")
                    If Integer.TryParse(strValue, value) Then
                        student.StudentId = value
                    Else
                        MessageBox.Show("Error Converting StudentID to Integer")
                        Exit Sub
                    End If

                    student.FName = sr.ReadLine().Trim("[]")
                    student.LName = sr.ReadLine().Trim("[]")

                    strValue = sr.ReadLine().Trim("[]")
                    If Integer.TryParse(strValue, value) Then
                        student.ScMark = value
                    Else
                        MessageBox.Show("Error Converting ScMark to Integer")
                        Exit Sub
                    End If

                    strValue = sr.ReadLine().Trim("[]")
                    If Integer.TryParse(strValue, value) Then
                        student.EnMark = value
                    Else
                        MessageBox.Show("Error Converting EnMark to Integer")
                        Exit Sub
                    End If

                    strValue = sr.ReadLine().Trim("[]")
                    If Integer.TryParse(strValue, value) Then
                        student.MaMark = value
                    Else
                        MessageBox.Show("Error Converting MaMark to Integer")
                        Exit Sub
                    End If

                    Students.Add(student)
                Catch ex As Exception
                    MessageBox.Show("Error reading file. All records may not have been created.")
                End Try
            End While

            MessageBox.Show("Done!")
        End Using


    End Sub

    Private Class StudInfo
        Public FName As String
        Public LName As String
        Public StudentId As Integer
        Public ScMark As Integer
        Public EnMark As Integer
        Public MaMark As Integer
    End Class

End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends a bit on the exact format of your text file.

If the file only contains the data  for the two students (no brackets or blank lines), then all you need to do is to open the file and read 6 lines, add the data to your structure. and read the next 6 lines. If you have an undetermined number of students in the text file, then you would be better using a `List`. Other wise you're goiing to have to use extra processing time to `Redim` the array each time you want to add a student and keep track of the array size an all sorts of messing around.

However. Lets go with the most straightforward answer and assume your data has no brackets or blank lines and that there are only two students.

This code should work just fine. If you have a different definite number of students, then you will need to change the size of the `Students` array.

I'm also assuming that the data is correctly formatted and there are no non-numeric characters are in the lines where there shouldn't be.

```
Private Sub ReadStudentInfo()
    'create an array that hold student details
    Dim Students(2) As StudInfo
    Dim index As Integer = 0
    ' read from text file 
    Dim datafile As New StreamReader("some.text")

    Do Until datafile.EndOfStream
        Dim tempStudent As StudInfo
        With tempStudent
            Integer.TryParse(datafile.ReadLine, .StudentId)
            .FName = datafile.ReadLine
            .LName = datafile.ReadLine
            Integer.TryParse(datafile.ReadLine, .ScMark)
            Integer.TryParse(datafile.ReadLine, .EnMark)
            Integer.TryParse(datafile.ReadLine, .MaMark)
        End With
        Students(index) = tempStudent
        index = index + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

If your text file does contain blank lines, just insert

```
            datafile.ReadLine()
```

between each line of data - like this

```
            Integer.TryParse(datafile.ReadLine, .ScMark)
            datafile.ReadLine()
            Integer.TryParse(datafile.ReadLine, .EnMark)
```

If you have the brackets in your text file, then you'll need to add extra code to remove them.